# Angular2 Child Routes

Tags: angular

```
const itemRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: ItensComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'lista', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'lista', component: ListaItensComponent },
        { path: 'novo', component: NovoItemComponent },
        { path: 'edita/:id', component: EditaItemComponent }
    ]
}
```

];

ListaItensComponent

```
 editaItem(id: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['../edita', id], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

}

Como eu posso retornar ao ListaItensComponent após editar o item ??

Answer (score 1):

Você pode retornar utilizando o comando `history.back();` que acredito não ser a melhor forma, ou utilizando `this._router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this._routeParams });` que no meu caso funciona, porém minha configuração da rota é diferente da sua.

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: MarcaListComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: MarcaFormComponent }
]);
```

Para adicionar um novo item eu utilizo a rota de edição, porém passando um id igual a zero.
Abaixo segue os dois métodos (adicionar, editar):

```
add() {
    if (this.enableAdd) {
        this._router.navigate([0], { relativeTo: this._route });
    }
}

edit() {
    if (this.enableEdit) {
        this._router.navigate([this.selectedItem.id], { relativeTo: this._route });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi queres aceder ao objeto que queres editar no component EditaItemComponent. Tu através do route não podes enviar objetos para outros componentes, logo a maneira mais fácil será utilizar um serviço que tem a tua lista de objetos e quando queres editar um objeto utilizas o route para passar o id e depois no componente EditaItemComponent acedes a esse serviço e fazes o get ao objeto que corresponde ao id para edição.